# Fix stripped screws in a doorframe

Tags: screws, door-frame

My kids playroom door got beat up, and we managed to pull the screws out of the jamb.  Tips to fix it?  I've heard drill out + dowel + redrill, anything else?[image]

Comment: pound a glue-laden golf tee into the hole and re-drill.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order of my personal preference:

**Option 1: Go Go Gadget Screws**

Get longer screws that reach the framing. Don't run them in so tight as to pull the jamb out of position. All-thread screws might bite into the jamb somewhat to prevent movement.

**Option 2: A Square Peg in a Round Hole**
Fill the holes with wood glue and tap in wood "dowels" shaved from a scrap block. They don't need to be perfectly round but should fit snugly. Let it dry well and re-drill with a 1/8" bit.

**Option 3: Bulk Up for Success**
Procure screws with the same head size but a larger shank. They're somewhat specialty, so try an old-school hardware store rather than a home improvement box.

**Option 4: See You on the Flipside**
Drill and countersink the hinge holes in an opposing stagger pattern. Pilot with 1/8" bit.

Comment: +1 esp. for not tightening longer screws too much

Comment: expanding on option 4 .... buy a hinge with different hole pattern

Comment: For option 1, I assume still drill some ‘pilot hole’ length in for the longer screw?  I always worry about splitting wood

Comment: Option 2 - matchsticks with no heads work fine, as do unused splints for lighting pipes, or even unused iceblock sticks trimmed.

Comment: The reason you'd pilot into the framing is mostly to keep the screw from glancing off the face of the stud--the outer screw(s) tend to be close to the edge. It's not necessary, though, since it's softwood and isn't visible.

Comment: Or Option 5: Use the existing screws/holes and pack with [rawlplugs](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-a-Rawl-Plug), although you might need to make the existing holes a little bigger.

Comment: Plastic plugs are an interesting idea, but I'm not sure I'd consider them sticky enough for a high load dynamic applications such as this. The polyethylene might have a tendency to shift.

Comment: @isherwood thanks, I used #10 2" screws, self drilling.  works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Fill the holes with wooden toothpicks. The screws will bite into them.

Comment: a bit of glue on them helps them stay in.

Comment: This is the easiest thing to try first.

Answer (score 2):

Plastic rawplugs will do a good job, can always put some adhesive in the hole first

Comment: What adhesive do you recommend for polyethylene?

Comment: Thanks. I already tried the long screws. +1 though

Answer (score 1):

If going to plug up hole and redrill, I find that some shim stock, sold for framing purposes works great.  I use a utility knife to cut strips, and then pack them into the existing hole with some wood glue.  The next day I predrill holes for the screws.  If the screws are badly rusted, I try to find replacements.

If there are three bad hinges, it's sometimes possible to do one at a time, which eliminates the need to pull the door.

Comment: OTOH, doing them all at once means that it's glue today, install tomorrow, done, instead of glue today, screw tomorrow, glue the day after, screw the day after that... until a week has gone by. ;)

Comment: Two different approaches.  One does what it can immediately.  The other incrementally permits incremental fixes.  With different risks.